# jQuery only partially working on Click function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this bit of jQuery (excuse the horrible html appends - these will be eventually shortened!)

```
$(function () {
  $(".follow").click(function () {
    var element = $(this);
    var I = element.data("userid");
    var info = 'id=' + I;
    var Something = $('#latestbettors tr[data-userid=' + I + ']').find('td:eq(0)').text();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "follow.php",
      data: info,
      success: function () {
        $('.follow[data-userid=' + I + ']').fadeOut(200).hide();
        $('.following[data-userid=' + I + ']').fadeIn(200).show();
        if ($('#yourfollowers table tr > td:contains("You arent currently following any bettors")')) {
          $('#yourfollowers table tr:contains("You aren\'t currently following any bettors")').remove();
        }
        if ($('#yourfollowers tr:contains("' + I + '")') && $('#yourfollowers tr > td:contains("' + Something + '")').length < 1) $('#yourfollowers table').fadeIn(200).append("<tr data-userid='" + I + "'><td>" + Something + "</td><td><a href='#'data-userid='" + I + "' class='following'></a><a href='#' data-userid='" + I + "' class='follow' style='display:none'></a></td></tr>");
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});

$(function () {
  $(".following").click(function () {
    var element = $(this);
    var J = element.data("userid");
    var infos = 'id=' + J;

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "unfollow.php",
      data: infos,
      success: function () {
        $('.following[data-userid=' + J + ']').fadeOut(200).hide();
        $('.follow[data-userid=' + J + ']').fadeIn(200).show();
        $('#yourfollowers tr[data-userid=' + J + ']').fadeOut(200).remove();

        if ($('#yourfollowers table tr').length == 0) {
          $('#yourfollowers table').append('<tr><td>You aren\'t currently following any bettors</td></tr>');
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

I have two tables - latest bettors and following. The latest bettors table includes all of the newly signed up users with a follow button beside each (or following if the user is following them) ... The following table includes all of the users the user is following with a following button beside each.

When the user clicks the follow button in the 'latest bettors' table it appends the user they have followed to the 'following table' - this works well. However when the user clicks on the 'following' button after this in the 'following' table - nothing happens? Why is this?

Comment: It is hard to read your code.  Please format it

Comment: Sorry I'm terrible at formatting my code (noob) - by all means edit it if you wish :)

Comment: @AndrewCharlton, that's not an excuse, http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For dynamically generated elements, event should be delegated from one of static parents of the element or document object, you can use `on` or `delegate` method:

```
$(document).on('click', '.following', function(){
```

If you are using jQuery below 1.7 version you can also use `delegate` method:

```
$(document).delegate('.following', 'click', function(){
```

<sub>Updated by @[Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1008575/exception):</sub>

And also you can use

```
$('.following').live('click', function(){
```

But `live` is deprecated in latest versions of jQuery. It may work now if you are using old jQuery version, but it may not work with latest version of jQuery you use.

Comment: perhaps because some of it is generated via php too?

Comment: @AndrewCharlton `on` doesn't work with previous versions of jQuery, which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: yes live works great for me :) - Should I update my jquery though?

Comment: @AndrewCharlton if you plan to update your jQ library (I suggest) make sure to test everything after.

Comment: @AndrewCharlton Yes, it's better to use latest versions, but if you want to use jQuery 1.6.1 use `delegate` instead of `live` method.